# What are root and Ubuntu password in LXC ubuntu:16.04 container?

Tags: 16.04, password, lxc

I created a Ubuntu container

```
lxc launch ubuntu images:ubuntu/xenial mycontainer
```

I can access the container using

```
lxc exec mycontainer bash
```

I found mysel logged in as root without asking any password

I see that there is a "ubuntu" user defined

How can I access a software installed in the container (e.g. webmin) which asks for a username and password?

What are the default passwords?

Comment: Just to clarify here: `lxc launch ...` is using LXD, not LXC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual password for these kinds of things is: `ubuntu` with the username `ubuntu`

You may need to set the password using the command `passwd`
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596108/how-do-i-change-my-password-in-linux)

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case for 18.04 LTS; the user appears to be `ubuntu`, but when I enter `ubuntu` as the password, it rejects it.

Comment: Does not work for 22LTS/jammy either.

Answer (score 13):

After creating container "first" need set password for user "ubuntu"

```
lxc exec first -- /bin/bash
passwd ubuntu
exit
```

Then you can attach to console(or ssh - if ssh installed and configured)

```
lxc console first
```

**UPDATE**:
 As Piter wrote "You don't even have to enter the bash-shell"

```
lxc exec first -- passwd ubuntu
```

Comment: You don't even have to enter the bash-shell: 'lxc exec first -- passwd ubuntu' worked for me as well.

Comment: @PeterGloor Thanks for the suggestion! I tried the command you mentioned, and it works as advertised. Terentev: Might you consider incorporating Peter's suggestion into your answer?